# parse bash time function to seconds

Tags: bash

I have this bit of info from a bash script. How can I keep only the time?

```
"real\t0m3.21s"
```

Needs to be

```
3.21s
```

The output is produced from time function.

Comment: What if the output is `2m3.21s` -- you don't care about the 2 minutes?

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion for the parameter expansion operators you can use to remove `real\t*m` from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -n 's/real\\t0m//p' <<< "real\t0m3.21s"
```

Replace "read\t0m" for nothing and print